# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'room') Couldn't Find the solution

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I was working on a project using MERN stacks using socket.io but I get some error while working on it.
While connecting with socket.io I was able to get the room id but it said **couldn't read properties of undefined (reading 'room')**

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    // For Users in Room
    const { room } = socket.handshake.query;
    const { user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, room: room });
    if (room) {
        console.log(user) // This value is showing in console.
        socket.join(user.room); // But here's the error begins.
        // io.in(user.room).emit('allUsersData', {
        //     room: user.room,
        //     users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)
        // });
        // console.log(room)

    }
```

This is the output I see.

```
{ id: 'Z1u-V5zH_VAR1It0AAAC', room: "inv6))8mdb'odz8" }
undefined
F:\Programming\Repositories\my_share\server\server.js:26
        socket.join(user.room);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'room')
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (F:\Programming\Repositories\my_share\server\server.js:26:26)
    at Namespace.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Namespace.emitReserved (F:\Programming\Repositories\my_share\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:56:22)
```

Comment: You have two outputs in your log but only one active `console.log` in your code. I find it quite hard to believe that some value would be defined in one line, but undefined in the next. What I suspect: the valid output you are seeing is from somewhere within `addUser` and the `undefined` output is from `console.log(user)` Add the code of ` addUser` to the question

Comment: Or change this `console.log(user)` to `console.log("foo", user)` and see what is printed, so you can be sure, the logged object is really printed by that specific console.log ...

Comment: @derpirscher that logged object is coming from above code, there is no console log in addUser function.

Comment: When I look at your output I see `undefined` being logged directly before the error. And as `console.log(user)` is the last console output before the line referenced in the error, I can only come to the conclusion, that the logged `undefined` is the result of `console.log(user)` and the other (valid) output above must originate from somewhere else. This is the only explanation which fits both, the shown code and output.